# Purpose of function prototypes

Tags: c++, function

From a class exercise:

```
Fill in the blanks to print
"it works!" on the screen,
type in the function
prototype before its call.
```

```
void some_func();
int main()
{
    some_func();
    return 0;
}
void some_func() {
    cout << "it works!" << endl;
}
```

If I am using the function right after I declared it, why did this code define it in the end?
I mean, we could just have declared and defined and then call in the main. 
I don't get the point of declaring, calling and then defining.

I have just started learning about functions. I am a beginner.

*EDIT from perspective of C.S. teacher*: This student is wondering about the purpose of function prototypes generally. This is a typical case of teaching a concept with an example that is simple enough to master, yet so simple it doesn't yet serve a purpose. Perhaps it is still not the right question for StackOverflow, but should at least be closed for the right reason. It is a very common and well-defined question.

Comment: All questions on stackoverflow.com must include all information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Dodgy links to suspicious external web sites are not acceptable. This question must be [edit]ed, and the link replaced with all relevant information, as plain text.

Comment: It is basically to prepare you for using header files, no other reason. When your project grows beyond a single file, you will want a header file(s) with function declarations only and separate cpp file(s) with function definitions.

Comment: I'll post my answer soon as I'm done taking a picture of it. My phone is charging though, so it might take a couple of hours...

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly fine to put the definition before the use in most cases. The only time the C language requires you to put a non-definition declaration before use is when two or more functions use each other, so one or more of them have to be declared before the others can be defined. I prefer building up a module from smaller/lower parts to larger parts, so I generally put function definitions before the routines that use them. However, the teacher may be presenting this exercise to teach concepts about declarations, not to teach you to use a particular style.

If you have not yet learned about them, you will soon learn about *header* files. As programs grow more complicated, we no longer want to keep all the source code in one file, for several reasons. (It becomes more difficult to manage more code. Grouping functions by some type of service they provide or some sort of common data they work with can help us organize the source code and keep it more sensible to human understanding. It also makes it easier to reuse functions in other programs.) Once we break a program up into separate source files, some definitions will no longer be in the same source file as routine to use them. So, instead of definitions, we put declarations in the source files as necessary. A routine `foo` defined in one source file, and other files that use it will have declarations of `foo`.

This brings up a problem that declarations are then repeated in many places. That becomes a burden to maintain—any time the definition of `foo` is changed, all the declarations of it have to be changed. And it is easy to make mistakes, which can bugs in the program, because declaring a function differently from how it is defined can cause undesired behavior. To deal with this, declarations for one set of things, typically all those defined in one source file (and intended to be used by other source files), are gathered into one file, called a header file and typically given a name ending in `.h`. Then other source files merely include the header files that contain the declarations they need, using an `#include` directive that tells the compiler to include contents the header file in the current compilation as if it were a part of the current source file.

Because of this, you must learn about various ways declarations can be used, including putting them before functions that use the declared functions.

(I would include C++, but its declarations can be more complicated.)

Comment: Eric, you took your time to write all this and make it as clear as possible. I AM REALLY HAPPY you did this. I now see the purpose of declaring it, and then defining it. I could have just proceeded, but I didn't quite get this point, and I don't like moving on with uncertainties. The books I read all took it for granted, like "we declare it and theeeeeen define it, and that's it". So, I kinda didn't know why one had to/could do that, but now I know. THANK YOU VEEEEEERY MUCH.